# radio reset accord

Tags: honda, audio, accord

I've been trying to mess around in the touch screen android system for couple days trying to figure out a way to install apps like Waze and any app for the matter of fact.

I went into the diagnostic menu (holding the power + brightness button + menu) i think, tapping the bottom option and holding "menu" again for a couple seconds.

Long story short, when i start my car, both screens turn on but nothing is displayed afterwards. On the top screen, Lanewatch + backup camera? works, but nothing else, screen is blank otherwise. & on the bottom screen, the startup animation comes on then screen goes blank.

I've tried removing the negative battery terminal for 10-20mins hoping it would reset anything thats wrong but having the same problem. I've held down the power button next to the cd player for 10+secs and nothing. I've tried getting back into the diagnostic menu but its not coming up. I'm out of ideas to reset the system, any other ways i should try?

Thanks [image]

Comment: Strange that the battery reset trick didn't work, you may want to try again but leave it disconnected longer. What is the year/model/engine/trim of the vehicle?

Comment: Honda accord ex-l 2.4L 2016

Comment: the battery is unplugged for 1 day

Answer (score 1):

You can try the hard reset.

1. Put the car in accessory, but not running
2. Turn on the audio system (even though it does not completely start)
3. Open the hood
4. Access the fuse box
5. Remove the audio fuse for about 15 seconds and reinsert it (refer to owner's manual to locate correct fuse)
6. System should reset

Check to see if it boots completely, and if functions return. If not, you may need to take it to a dealership or automotive electronics specialist.

Comment: unfortunately did not help

Answer (score 1):

This process will reset the radio, however you will need the radio code.
If the car was purchased new, the code card should be available.  If not, you will need VIN and radio ser number to get code from Honda. 
https://radio-navicode.honda.com/

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!  Which process will reset the radio? Something he already tried?  Could you [edit](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/posts/58178/edit) your answer to be more clear on how to solve his problem?

Answer (score 0):

I did all what in the internet to reset the navi but it didn't work . So I went to the dealer and they reinstall the software of navi  system thru flash memory they put it into the USB port under the navi and it took about 35 minutes and the system com back again .it cost me about 70 $ . I think that I played on the boot loader sitting and that what caused the problem.